# Is R = {(a, b) | a, b ∈ Z, ∃k ∈ Z s.t. (a − b) = 3k} an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not quite sure what ∃k ∈ Z s.t. (a − b) = 3k describes in the relation. Perhaps if I could figure out what that means, I could prove R is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

The question also states that if R is an equivalence relation, I should describe its equivalence classes. Could someone explain more clearly to me what equivalence classes are and how to "describe" them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you learnt congruence relations?

Comment: It means that $a-b=3k$ for some integer $k$, so their difference is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$(8,5)\in R$ because $8-5=3=3\times 1~~~~$  (and $1\in \mathbb{Z}$). 
 $(8,2)\in R$ because $8-2=6=3\times 2$.  
$(2,8)\in R$ because $2-8=-6=3\times -2$.
 $(2,2)\in R$ because $2-2=0=3\times 0$.
  However $(8,3)\notin R$ because $8-3=5=3\times (5/3)$, and $5/3\notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Of the three properties you need to prove, the trickiest one is transitivity.  If $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$, then $a-b=3m$ and $b-c=3n$.  Sum these to get $a-c=3m+3n=3(m+n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are working with an equivalence relation, then you end up with lots of things that are considered the same by that relation. Let $S$ be an equivalence relation. Consider $1Sx$, which is the set of $x$ such that $x$ is equivalent to $1$. This would is the equivalence class for $1$. So if $1S5$, then $5$ is in the equivalence class of $1$ and, **while using** $S$, the two can be used interchangeably.

For your particular $R$, you just have to work through the definitions to show reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 0):

***Hint:***

$\exists k \in \Bbb Z$ such that $(a - b) = 3k \iff 3 \ | \ (a - b)$

Think about the properties of divisibility. $a \ | \  0 \;\; \forall a \in \Bbb Z, \;\; a \ |  \ b \iff a \ | \ (-b)$ and $a\ | \ b,  \ a\ | \ c \implies a$ divides any linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

Say $R$ is an equivalence relation. Then the set $[a]=\{b \ | \ (a,b) \in R \}$ is the equivalence class of $a$.  That is the set of all elements *related* to $a$ in $R$.

Shouldn't be hard to finish this off.